# Astropy.model 2DGaussian issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, gaussian, astropy

I'm trying to a 2D Gaussian to a fits image in order to find the brightest object in the image.  I am trying to follow the 1D example here http://docs.astropy.org/en/v0.3.2/modeling/index.html.  My code looks like

```
import numpy as np
import astropy.io.fits as fits
import os
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
import matplotlib as plt

data = fits.getdata('AzTECC100.fits')
med = np.median(data) 
data = data - med
data = data[0,0,:,:]

w = models.Gaussian2D(data, np.mean(data),np.mean(data), np.std(data),np.std(data),)


fit_w = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

max_index = np.where(data >= np.max(data))
x0 = max_index[1] #Middle of X axis
y0 = max_index[0]
sigma = np.std(data)
amp = np.max(data)

x = np.arange(0, data.shape[1], 1)
y = np.arange(0, data.shape[0], 1)


A = 1 / (2*sigma**2)
eq =  amp*np.exp(-A*((x-x0)**2 + (y-y0)**2))
g = fit_w(w, x, y,eq)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(x, y,eq, 'ko')
plt.plot(x, g, label='Gaussian')
circle = Circle((x0, y0), 4, facecolor ='none', edgecolor = 'red', linewidth = 1)
 ax.scatter(x0, y0,s = 10, c = 'red', marker = 'x')
```

While the error I'm getting is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-33-45f671ba149d> in <module>()
----> 1 g = fit_w(w, x, y,eq)

/Users/samclyne/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/astropy/modeling/fitting.pyc in __call__(self, model, x, y, z, weights, maxiter, acc, epsilon, estimate_jacobian)
    557             self.objective_function, init_values, args=farg, 
Dfun=dfunc,
    558             col_deriv=model_copy.col_fit_deriv, maxfev=maxiter, epsfcn=epsilon,
--> 559             xtol=acc, full_output=True)
    560         _fitter_to_model_params(model_copy, fitparams)
    561         self.fit_info.update(dinfo)

/Users/samclyne/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, 
full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    378     m = shape[0]
    379     if n > m:
--> 380         raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed 
M=%s' % (n, m))
    381     if epsfcn is None:
    382         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

TypeError: Improper input: N=65541 must not exceed M=65536
```

I understand that the number of parameters cannot exceed the amount of data points there are but I'm uncertain whats causing it or where I can fix it.

I'm sorry if I don't give enough info  in my question.  I'm not a great coder and I'm new to this website

Comment: [Scipy docs say](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm (lm) doesn't work when the number of observations is less than the number of variables. I don't know astropy, but it is probably the same problem. Does astropy have any other fitting algorithms?

Comment: Don't put `data` as the first argument to your model: that's how you end up with too many parameters. The examples at http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/index.html#models-and-fitting-astropy-modeling show how it works.

Comment: I wonder if the data (`AzTECC100.fits`) is publicly available? Could it be possible to answer this question without having an access to the data being used?

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes in your code but the one responsible for this particular crash is that you do not create the model correctly: the first argument to `w = models.Gaussian2D()` should be the amplitude and not `data`! Data have nothing to do with a "model" which is a theoretical dependence/function that you plan to *fit to data*.

Using data similarly generated as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560755/8033585, specifically,

```
y, x = np.indices((51,51))
data = 3 * np.exp(-0.7 * ((x - 24)**2 + (y - 26)**2))
```

and also commenting out lines that do not work, here is a modification of your code that should work (note: I increased the radius of the circle by 30x and intensity plot is on the log scale):

```
import astropy.io.fits as fits
import os
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data = fits.getdata('AzTECC100.fits')
med = np.median(data) 
# data = data - med
# data = data[0,0,:,:] # NOT SURE THIS IS NEEDED!

fit_w = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()

y0, x0 = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(data), data.shape)
sigma = np.std(data)
amp = np.max(data)

w = models.Gaussian2D(amp, x0, y0, sigma, sigma)

yi, xi = np.indices(data.shape)

g = fit_w(w, xi, yi, data)
print(w)
model_data = g(xi, yi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
eps = np.min(model_data[model_data > 0]) / 10.0
# use logarithmic scale for sharp Gaussians
ax.imshow(np.log(eps + model_data), label='Gaussian') 
circle = Circle((g.x_mean.value, g.y_mean.value),
                30 * g.x_stddev.value, facecolor ='none',
                edgecolor = 'red', linewidth = 1)

ax.add_patch(circle)
plt.show()
```

Printed model parameters are:

```
Model: Gaussian2D
Inputs: ('x', 'y')
Outputs: ('z',)
Model set size: 1
Parameters:
    amplitude x_mean y_mean     x_stddev        y_stddev    theta
    --------- ------ ------ --------------- --------------- -----
          3.0   24.0   26.0 0.0881184627394 0.0881184627394   0.0
```

---

#### NOTES:

You will find a great deal of examples of using `astropy.modeling` and an important discussion about the effect of the "scale" of the image data (order of magnitude) here: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/6269 According to that issue, it may be helpful to "normalize" your image (rescale intensity to bring it into a "reasonable" range). Also follow links to notebooks that may provide further examples, such as https://github.com/ibusko/experiments_specviz/blob/master/experiment_normalization.ipynb Unfortunately these examples are for 1D data but can be easily expanded to 2D data.